# Merge different Eclipse packages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jsdt

The Eclipse project offers several [download packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), each focused on some set of languages and/or execution platforms: C/C++, JS web development, Modeling tools etc.

Now, Eclipse is basically a single platform with multiple plugins / combinable repositories etc. But - how do I square that with the discrete download packages? Specifically, how do I achieve a "union of download package X and download package Y" for doing two kinds of development with the same IDE?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is:

- Download one 'flavor' of Eclipse
- Run it
- Go to **Help | Install New Software...**,
- Select the official Eclipse repository
- Install additional packages which sound like they belong in the second flavor you want

However, this doesn't get you quite what you wanted. For example, I did this with Eclipse CDT and JSDT-related packages, but I still can't started a new project which is JS-focused - I still see only the same kinds of projects I saw with just the CDT download.

Comment: If you start with Eclipse for C/C++ Developers and install JavaScript plug-ins into it, the default perspective is _C/C++_. Switch to the _JavaScript_ perspective to have JS-focused menus, icons, etc. You can also use the [p2 director (with the parameter `-roaming`)](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) to build your own Eclipse package that can be shipped.